# Jinja2 templates, remove the carriage return

Tags: python, jinja2

I use Jinja2 templates for a lot of network device configurations but now I need to make a specific line of names for reporting purposes.

A Jinja2 script I use is as follows

```
{% for name in names -%}
{{name}} OR 
{% endfor -%}
```

It gives me

```
name1 OR
name2 OR
name3 OR
```

that in a text I make it look like what I need is "name1 OR name2 OR name3 OR" then "name1 OR name2 OR name3"

I am trying to research on creating a Jinja2 that will take me close or to the final format that I need.

Could someone help me with this, It would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So do you want that trailing `OR` or not?  That's not super clear from your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `loop.last` to prevent outputting **OR** within the last iteration and use `-` to remove the carriage returns.

```
{% for name in names -%}
{{name}}{{ " OR " if not loop.last else "" -}}
{% endfor -%}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the `{%-` as start tag in order to drop whitespace for previous expression:

```
from jinja2 import Template

template = '''
{% for name in names -%}
{{name}} OR
{%- endfor -%}
'''
print (Template(template).render(names=['a', 'b', 'c']))
```

This returns following, which is probably not what you actually wanted.. :)

```
<newline>
a ORb ORc OR
```

So in order to get the wanted result there are at least two following options for template:

```
{{ names | join(' OR ') }}
```

or even shorter variant:

```
{{ " OR ".join(names) }}
```